# How can I observe the "special price" activation? When the special price becomes active

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

How can I observe when a Special price becomes enabled?
You set a date from and to, but which observer is launched when special price becomes available and unavailable?

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Comment: Sorry, this is 1.9.1

Comment: Off the top of my head, i dont recall any such event. Special prices availability and actioning would be dealt with via the products price model object. Maybe if you explain what you are trying to achieve someone can help with that?

Comment: I'm updating an external service, an external DB, so I observe changes in product descriptions, and I observe the sales (to keep the stock updated). So I also need to update special price on the DB when it becomes enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't observe that.
Magento reads that on the fly each time (crazy)